# Converting a nested array to JSON

Tags: java, android, json

I've got a nested array in Java, something like this:

```
String [] [] x;
```

In my code I'm converting it into a JSON string to pass it across the @JavascriptInterface bridge to javascript running in a WebView using this code:

```
String ret = (new JSONArray(Arrays.asList(x))).toString();
```

This is working fine on newer devices, but in testing an older device I'm running into very weird behavior.  Instead of creating a nice string like this:

```
"[ [ 1.234, 5, 7 ], [ 23.456, 7, 8 ] ]"
```

it's creating a string that looks like this:

```
'["[Ljava.lang.String;@405ba988"]'
```

As far as I can tell, all the objects I am using (JSONArray, Arrays) and the corresponding member functions (toString, asList) have been around since API level 1.

Am I doing something wrong, or is there something I am missing that I need to do to accommodate earlier versions of Android?

Comment: Mate you .toString the object???

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Before Android 4.4(api 19) the [following](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/libcore/+/android-4.3.1_r1/json/src/main/java/org/json/JSONArray.java) was the constructor code:

```
public JSONArray(Collection copyFrom) {
    this();
    Collection<?> copyFromTyped = (Collection<?>) copyFrom;
    values.addAll(copyFromTyped);
}
```

As you can see it just adds the members of the collection, this is why you get `'["[Ljava.lang.String;@405ba988"]'` no additional processing is done on them.

In Android 4.4(api 19) some functionality was added and changed [wrap](https://developer.android.com/reference/org/json/JSONObject.html#wrap(java.lang.Object)) method was added to `JSONObject` which can handle an array and the same constructor from `JSONArray` was [changed](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/libcore/+/android-4.4_r1.1/json/src/main/java/org/json/JSONArray.java) to use it:

```
public JSONArray(Collection copyFrom) {
    this();
    if (copyFrom != null) {
        for (Iterator it = copyFrom.iterator(); it.hasNext();) {
            put(JSONObject.wrap(it.next()));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: ah, so... for api < 19 I just need to emulate the latter routine.

Comment: You need to create a collection of `JSONArray` and then you can add them with the same constructor.